# Why should I use an async function in the callback in the mongoDB middleware?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, async-await, middleware

So, I am doing a course on web development and I'm doing mongoDB middleware stuff and I noticed the teacher was using an async function instead of a simple one and I really don't see the difference, I mean I understand the concept but I don't see how would it change the code's behavior.

```
personSchema.pre("save", async function(){
    console.log("Saving...");
});

personSchema.post("save", async function(){
    console.log("SAVED!");
});
```

Comment: If the callback function involves a DB operation, it needs to `await` for the promise to resolve or reject. That's why your middlware has `async function()`

Comment: Yes, i get it now, I tried without the async keyword and the behaivor was the same (in my simple case), thanks!

Comment: If your callback function doesn't involve an asynchronous operation, there is no point to use the `async` keyword in front of the `function`

Comment: That function is the `callback( )` from the **save** command. As it was said by @OzgurSar, you only need async if the callback executes asynchronous code. This is not always the case, so "async" as a rule is just playing silly.